# Gradle multi-module project compilation fails with "classNotFoundExceptions" from dependencies mentioned in sub-modules

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi-module setup for a Java project with following structure.

```
mainApp
|--> core-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
           |--> implementation group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2-kernel', version: '1.7.8'
           |--> implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.13'
           |--> implementation files('libs/some_local.jar')
           |--> compile project(":lib-module")
           |--> compile project(":lib-another-module")
           |--> ...

|       
|--> lib-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
           |--> implementation group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
           |--> implementation files('libs/another_local.jar')
           |--> ...

|--> lib-another-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
           |--> implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
           |--> implementation files('libs/another_local.jar')
           |--> ...

| 
|--> settings.gradle
|--> build.gradle
|--> gradle.properties
```

In `mainApp/build.gradle` file I have a 'mentioned' sub-modules as

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs project('core-module').file("src")
            srcDirs project('lib-module').file("src")
            srcDirs project('lib-another-module').file("src")
        }
    }
}
```

If I **build individual sub-module it get compiled successfully** but when I run `./gradlew compileJava` at root , it fails with `classNotFoundExceptions` from the jars which I've already mentioned in sub-modules

```
> Task :core-module:compileJava
//successful
> Task :lib-module:compileJava
//successful
> Task :lib-another-module:compileJava
//successful
> Task :compileJava
/.../core-module/src/java/../OAuthUtils.java:12: error: package org.apache.http does not exist
import org.apache.http.Header;
...
//FAILED!
```

Here `./gradlew core-module:compileJava` works perfectly but compilation fails when invoked from root.

1. How shall I deal with it?
2. Is it because of some local jars referred from file-system?

**EDIT**

I found that the compilation of root `sourceSets{}` which is pointing to child `sub-module` is failing and individual `sub-module` compilation is successful.

But, I need this `sourceSets{}` for creating one monolithic jar of all `sub-module`

**Note:-** I'm not creating `fatJar` or `shadedJar` here, But I need to include all packages from all `sub-modules` without dependency jars.

Comment: I hope it helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106128/how-to-declare-common-dependencies-in-multimodule-gradle-project-on-parent-folde

Comment: It's exactly reverse in my case. My `dependencies` are different for different module. Hence, I can't put it centrally in `parent` module. Second, my individual sub-module `> Task :core-module:compileJava` is compiling but as a whole project compilation is failing which is sort of weird here?

Comment: Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63923161/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-at-class-java-2?noredirect=1#comment113036969_63923161

Comment: Added `jar { enabled = true }` in `sub-module` but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'm not creating `fatJar` or `shadedJar` here, But I need to include packages from all `sub-modules`

Comment: this what I'm looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027456/1665592 thnx everyone 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how I'm successfully able to create the one monolithic jar from all `sub-module`

```
jar  {
    dependsOn compileJava

    manifest {
            def userName = System.properties['user.name']
            def javaVersion = JavaVersion.current()

            attributes 'Manifest-Version' : "1.0"
            attributes 'Built-By' : userName
            attributes 'Created-By' : "Java Version: " + javaVersion
    }
    destinationDir(file("$buildDir/image"))
    baseName(jarName)

    from project('core-module').sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
    from project('lib-module').sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
    from project('lib-another-module').sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs
  
}
```